# LibGDX: TextureRegion renders correctly, but .getTexture() doesn't

Tags: libgdx, textures, texture-atlas

I have a TextureRegion that I get from an atlas map (which in turn I get from the Asset Manager), eg

```
AssetManager am = myGame.getAssetManager();
TextureAtlas atlas = am.get("my.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
TextureRegion object = atlas.findRegion("myobject");
```

Now when I draw the object with

```
batch.draw(object, ...);
```

the object is drawn correctly, but if I do

```
batch.draw(object.getTexture(), ...);
```

it is drawn as garbage. Is this expected? I thought it should work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved. Trying with bigger objects from the same texture atlas, I see that getTexture() actually returns the whole atlas image, and this is by design, see eg [this question](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5573)